# sonata admin - how to give custom query to admin class

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I Am Developing website using sonata-admin Bundle in Symfony2

I Have Two Entity UserOne(id,name,pass ...) And UserTwo(id ,user_one_id ,...)

this two table are related by **one two many** using UserOne(id)->UserTwo(user_one_id)

each records of user_one table are admin of related company and 
each records of user_two table are employees of related user_one(id) company

```
user_one            ------------------    user_two

1 - james - ****    ------------------    1 - 1 - employee1

2 - kevin - ****    ------------------    2 - 1 - employee2

3 - jack  - ****    ------------------    3 - 2 - employee1
```

when user of user_one table login they get admin panel which is developed using sonata-admin
I Have Requirement To Give only that employee of user_two to admin which user_one_id match to login admin means userone(id)

for example if james is login and open dashboard for user management then only employee1 and employee2 is shown

i have created admin class of UserTwo Entity for Admin functionality (UserTwoAdmin.php)
but problem is that when james open dashboard all the records of user_two table is shown
i want to filter to show only those data which id match to login id

Comment: Take a look at createQuery method from your admin.

Comment: thanks for help it's done overriding createQuery() method